# How to remove strings in every after a character?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following string:

var string = [item.DropdownContents.split("\n")];

```
[cat = Account Maintenance] Cancellation
[cat = Account Maintenance] Migration
[cat = Billing] New Activation
[cat = Billing] Suspension
```

I would like to remove the strings on every after the closing bracket (]).  Is that possible?  FYI, the string is not an array.

Comment: You should include the code you've got so far in your question. Please review the SO [guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and have a quick read of [this blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) which contains a checklist of actions to take before asking a question.

Comment: Can you show what the result should be?  Have you looked into Regular Expressions?

Comment: let text = "[cat = Billing] Suspension";
text.split("]")[1];

Comment: I would like the part [cat = Billing]  to be removed.

Comment: The results that I want is:
Cancellation
Migration
New Activation
Suspension

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This regexp could solve this problem:

```
const inp =`[cat = Account Maintenance] Cancellation
            [cat = Account Maintenance] Migration
            [cat = Billing] New Activation
            [cat = Billing] Suspension`;

      inp.split('\n')
      .map( val=>val.replace(/\[.*\] /g,''))
      .join('\n')
```

The output is:

```
"Cancellation
Migration
New Activation
Suspension"
```

Second option is :

```
.map( val=>val.split('] ')[1])
```

but it's more prone to error, when `'] '` does not exist in given line.

Comment: The output that I want is:
Cancellation
Migration
New Activation
Suspension

Comment: Updated, you can join lines with empty string or a spacce to receive single line.

Comment: Thanks. However, the output you gave is the opposite.  What I want is:
Cancellation
Migration
New Activation
Suspension